# A working example for RegOpenCurrentUser

Tags: c++, registry

Could someone please provide me with an working example with RegOpenCurrentUser?
All it does for me is give me back ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

```
PHKEY keyCurrentUser = NULL;

lResult = RegOpenCurrentUser(KEY_READ, keyCurrentUser);
```

lResult is always 87. Don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't initialize the pointer, NULL is not an acceptable value.  Fix:

```
HKEY keyCurrentUser;
lResult = RegOpenCurrentUser(KEY_READ, &keyCurrentUser);
```