# Proper use of RegOpenCurrentUser

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, taskmanager

I went [here](http://dotnetbutchering.blogspot.sg/2008/03/c-how-to-disable-windows-task-manager.html) and made a test program to see if it actually disables the task manager. Basically a simple bool switch on then switch off to see if the task manager was actually disabled. It works as intended when i compiled and ran it.

Edit: the code now looks like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

void LockTaskManager(bool Lock);

void main(void) {
    LockTaskManager(true);

    cout << "Testing task manager disable." << endl;

    getchar();

    LockTaskManager(false);

    cout << "Testing task manager enabled." << endl;

    getchar();
}

void LockTaskManager(bool Lock)
{
    HKEY currKey;
    DWORD dwDisposition;
    DWORD dwType, dwSize;
    DWORD value;

    if (Lock)
        value = 1;
    else
        value = 0;

LRESULT lResult = RegOpenCurrentUser(KEY_WRITE, &currKey);
if (RegCreateKeyEx(currKey,
    TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\system"),
    0,
    NULL,
    0,
    KEY_SET_VALUE,
    NULL,
    &currKey,
    &dwDisposition) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
    dwType = REG_DWORD;
    dwSize = sizeof(DWORD);
    RegSetValueEx(currKey, TEXT("DisableTaskMgr"), 0, dwType, (PBYTE)&value, dwSize);
    RegCloseKey(currKey);
    }
}
```

However, after i moved the .exe to a guest user on the same computer, it does not disable the task manager. So i went to look into how and why it worked, from microsoft's MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724894(v=vs.85).aspx) i found that HKEY_CURRENT_USER does not change and requires the use of RegOpenCurrentUser to set the current key to the user that is running that program. i know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707978/a-working-example-for-regopencurrentuser) post but the answer is not conclusive.

So with that said, I wish to know the correct way to approach this. The goal here is to make whoever that runs the .exe of this code be unable to run task manager.

FYI, Just so whoever reads this knows, i intend to use this as a defense mechanism in the event a flag is triggered, i want to stop malicious entities from killing this process through task manager.

Comment: Command line is something like runas /user:guest "C:\path\crap.exe" see docs/help of that runas

Comment: I already set the project to run as an administrator under the project settings. i don't understand what are you trying to tell me.

Comment: @ Barmak Shemirani the cout says 0 when i compiled it, but yea i tried moving the .exe to another user and it still allows the task manager to run.

Comment: Have you checked  with regedit if the value was set?

Comment: I don't see any error reporting for `RegCreateKeyEx` and `RegSetValueEx`

Comment: @ Barmak Shemirani what do you mean? do you want to see return values for for both those functions?

Comment: Just add `lResult = RegCreateKeyEx(...) ... cout << lResult << "\n";` same thing for `RegSetValueEx`

Comment: Call `RegOpenCurrentUser` to get an `HKEY` for the current user, then pass that to `RegOpenKeyEx` to get the appropriate subkey.

Comment: @ Barmak Shemirani both functions return 0 after i added the checks

Comment: Ah ha! `RegCloseKey(hkey);`

Comment: if you not using  impersonating - no any sense in call `RegOpenCurrentUser`

Comment: *and requires the use of RegOpenCurrentUser to set the current key to the user that is running that program* - false. *set HKEY_CURRENT_USER such that no matter whoever runs this program*  - senseless. *it will set HKEY_CURRENT_USER to the user that runs this program and then disable the task manager for whoever that runs this code.* - both false and senseless

Comment: @ RbMm and why would that be so?

Comment: are you understand what you doing ? for what senseless call `RegOpenCurrentUser` ? and i point to your errors

Comment: and anyway you must got error access denied under guest on call `RegCreateKeyEx`

Comment: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` always refers to the currently logged in user. Your analysis is inconclusive. You really only need `RegOpenCurrentUser`, if the calling thread is impersonating a user different from the currently logged in user. This does not appear to be the case here, and the issue is a different one.

Comment: @ IInspectable the MSDN states [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724894(v=vs.85).aspx) that the HKEY_CURRENT_USER will not change if another user is loaded, and to load in the current user RegOpenCurrentUser is used to load the current user's key.

Comment: @YelofMan - and so what ?

Comment: @RbMm i am asking here because i don't know the correct approach to do this, no offence dude if you are going to answer me like that then don't bother, this conversation between me and you is over.

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724894.aspx) also says: *"The `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` key maps to the root of the **current user's branch** in the `HKEY_USERS` key."* Unless you explicitly load another user's profile (which your question does not claim you are), your issue is a different one, and `RegOpenCurrentUser` is not the solution. Don't ask about your solution. Ask about your problem instead. Start by implementing proper error reporting.

Answer (score 2):

what is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` ? this is really `\REGISTRY\USER\<UserSid>` where `<UserSid>` some sid. when process **first time** use `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` (root of the current user key is yet not opened) system query current user sid ( [`TokenUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379626(v=vs.85).aspx) ), convert sid to string, append `\REGISTRY\USER\` prefix, open and **cache** opened key. when process **next time** use, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` - used already opened and cached key. even if thread is impersonating - this change nothing. however some time we need access different user key, after impersonating. exactly for this situation and [`RegOpenCurrentUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724894(v=vs.85).aspx) and used. this api query current thread (or process) token for [`TokenUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379626(v=vs.85).aspx), format path based on **current** user sid, open `\REGISTRY\USER\<UserSid1>` and return handle to you. it not cache this handle, instead you must close it, when you no longer need the returned handle.

so at first senseless use `RegOpenCurrentUser` if you not impersonating current thread.

at second, this code always senseless:

```
LRESULT lResult = RegOpenCurrentUser(KEY_READ, &hkey);
if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,..
```

you not use returned `hKey` anyway. what sense open it in this case ?

need use it in place `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` !

```
LRESULT lResult = RegOpenCurrentUser(KEY_READ, &hkey);
if (RegCreateKeyEx(hKey,..
```

why code not worked under guest ? when you call `RegCreateKeyEx` and resulting key (`system` in your case) yet not exist - you need have `KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY` access to the parent (`Policies` key). however by default guest have not any write access to key. you simply have not `KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY` access. and `KEY_SET_VALUE` you also have not. sure that under guest call `RegCreateKeyEx` return `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` to you.